# Synchronized Independent column scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, masonry

I am developing a react web page, where I am using this kind of [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPd88.png).

But the height of the page could be even more than 4k px because I do not exactly know how many "boxes" will be displayed. Therefore, I added [scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyh5S.png) to the page.

Now I would like to have [aligned items to the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHEK.png) (top is already aligned by default) when the user is scrolling.
To achieve this, every column must scroll independently but synchronized at the same time.

Does someone have any suggestions on how to achieve this goal? It is some kind of parallax in combination with the masonry effect.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: so each column should be separately scrollable?

Comment: No, there should be only 1 scrollbar on the right side, but when user scrolls each column should "scroll" (or move) differently.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to contain each of the columns in their own div and then use the parallax effect to scroll all of them together.

Comment: And do u know how responsibility would work? In current state it is easy to do it responsible, but if each column would be div, it could makes some troubles.